# Website visible only to Registered users (non wp-admin)

Tags: user-registration, wp-login-form, content-restriction

I have created a page with a custom login using `wp_login_form()` function  but how can I redirect all visitors to that page in similar way described in [that topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178177/authentication-login-mechanism-non-wp-admin)?

My code looks like:

```
function redirect_to_login_if_guest() {

global $post;

if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() && $post->ID !== 4667 ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink(4667) );
    exit;
}
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'redirect_to_login_if_guest' );
```

but somehow is going into infinite loop instead of a login page. It looks like `wp_loaded` can't be used in my case.

Similar code moved to the `header.php'

```
global $post;

if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() && $post->ID != 4667 ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink(4667) );
    exit;
}
```

works flawless so still it points on triggering action on `wp_loaded`. Any thoughts?

Comment: How about trying it yourself?

Comment: My question contains that part too - just need directions or idea how to handle that kind of functionality. I don't need copy-paste code - that part I can do on my own.

Comment: Take a closer look at the conditions and you should realize why the "problem" you are describing occurs. Aside from that, if simply copy and pasting code, then thinking about what it does, before complaining it does the "wrong" thing, helps - just saying.

Comment: I have removed `$GLOBALS['pagenow']` and still is looping. IMO I need to replace that with something else.

Comment: What about checking that you are not in page `4667` before redirect to it again? It is simple.

Comment: Well, give a vote down without comments is not helpful. Topic closed because that kind of help is useless...

Comment: Jack, please do not destroy questions just because someone pointed out that you could just _try_ something when asking. The part wasn't there when you asked - see the [revision history](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/181356/revisions). Next thing, please take a look at the comments by @ialocin and cybmeta: You have an endless loop because you are redirecting to the same page even if you are already on it. How are you attempting to fix that?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about, I have commented and even [explained](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181356/website-visible-only-to-registered-users-non-wp-admin#comment264821_181356) to you, why I think this is not a good question. But let me spell it out for you, this is pretty much a no effort, bad quality and do my work for me question - IMHO - so you received my down vote. Besides there are helpful comments..

Comment: Down votes were before your explanation - that I'm talking about. Even my comment before cybmeta is states that I need to replace `$GLOBALS['pagenow']` with something else - in that case to check what current page is. Maybe I haven't time to post it back, but mine question is valid based on requirements so why is getting down votes? Take a look at Expression Engine StackExchange. It looks like Wordpress sections have non-friendly users. That's it.

Comment: @cybmeta I have updated code to check if page ID is 4667 but code still creates infinite loop.

Comment: @ialocin I'm not sitting 24 hrs at the computer to keep my post up to date and have question more solid and I don't do down votes on any topics on which I don't have nothing to tell.

Comment: Firstly, its a free world/system, so everyone can do what s|he wants - get over it. Secondly, sure, thats what I'm/we're doing - 24h 365 days a year of course. Thirdly, seems we've solved it, people on [wordpress.se] just suck - big time I guess. Last but not least, good luck getting help solving this.

Comment: F** it, you tried to make your question better, so I'm trying to help, see my answer.

Comment: Haha, I guess so, btw if you have shown some effort from the beginning, you have gotten that information from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the `$post` global isn't setup at the `wp_loaded` state. See:

- [When and Where is `global $post` Set and Available?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165736/22534)

for detailed information.

So use another hook, like `template_redirect`.

Comment: As an addition that blog post is useful: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-custom-loginpage/ It may help other users with similar issues which I had at the start.